# Надо записать в определенном месте файла .txt цифру на python

Tags: python, python-3.5, txt

Вот есть код

```
def fileReader(username1, lesson):
    f = open('marks.txt', 'r')
    f = f.read()
    info = f[f.find(username1):]
    info = info[:info.find('\n')]
    data  =info.split(';')
    
    
    for i in range(1,len(data)-1):
        dataS2 = data[i].split("<")
        if dataS2[0] == lesson:
            marks = dataS2[1]
    print(marks)

fileReader("mishagavura", "physiks")
```

Текст .txt файла:

```
mishagavura;algebra<10, 12, 11<;biology<10, 11, 12<;physiks<11, 11, 12, 12, 12<;
yakiwwi;algebra<12, 11, 10<;biology<10, 9, 8<;
```

как мне

```
mishagavura;algebra<10, 12, 11<;biology<10, 11, 12<;physiks<11, 11, 12, 12, 12(СЮДА ДОПИСАТЬ ЦИФРУ)<;
yakiwwi;algebra<12, 11, 10<;biology<10, 9, 8<;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
text = 'mishagavura;algebra<10, 12, 11<;biology<10, 11, 12<;physiks<11, 11, 12, 12, 12<; yakiwwi;algebra<12, 11, 10<;biology<10, 9, 8<;'

print(re.sub(r'(physiks.+?)<;', r'\1, 88<;', text))

# mishagavura;algebra<10, 12, 11<;biology<10, 11, 12<;physiks<11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 88<; yakiwwi;algebra<12, 11, 10<;biology<10, 9, 8<;
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
_str = "mishagavura;algebra<10, 12, 11<;biology<10, 11, 12<;physiks<11, 11, 12, 12, 12<;yakiwwi;algebra<12, 11, 10<;biology<10, 9, 8<;"

_list = _str.split(';')

new_list = []

for item in _list:
    if "physiks" == item[:len("physiks")]:
        item = item[:-1] + 'цмфра' + item[-1] + ';'
        new_list.append(item)
    elif item: new_list.append(item + ';')

    
print(''.join(new_list))
# mishagavura;algebra<10, 12, 11<;biology<10, 11, 12<;physiks<11, 11, 12, 12, 12цмфра<;yakiwwi;algebra<12, 11, 10<;biology<10, 9, 8<;

print(_str)
# mishagavura;algebra<10, 12, 11<;biology<10, 11, 12<;physiks<11, 11, 12, 12, 12<;yakiwwi;algebra<12, 11, 10<;biology<10, 9, 8<;
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!